# How do I specify several folders (/tmp and /var for instance) to mount in a same partition using the installer?

Tags: installation, mount, menu, folder

I my next Ubuntu installation I want to put /var and /tmp folders together in the same partition, but differente from /.

It's possible to do this from installer menu? As far as I know you can only select a folder from several options to mount in a certain partition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You can add both directories to the / partition or you can put /var and /tmp each on a seperate partition.

Alternative/workaround:

You can use a symlink and have /tmp store its files on a new directory like /var/temp/. That would require the following commands:

`sudo mkdir /var/temp/`
`sudo rm -rf /tmp/`
`sudo ln -s /var/temp/ /tmp/`

This also requires you to recreate the permissions to /tmp/.

`sudo chmod 777 /tmp`
`sudo chmod +t /tmp/`
`sudo chown root:root /tmp/`

<sub>Untested. Use at own risc:possible issue: you might have to set /var/temp/ with the same permissions as /tmp!</sub>